# Running a Python script (using an external module) through Android

Tags: android, python

I have written a Python script using SymPy (Python library for symbolic math). I want to run this script on my Android device, through an Android app:
I want the user to interact with the app which I will develop using the Android SDK, but I want the processing done by the Python script. The problem here is I am using an external module (SymPy) in that script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is SymPy pure Python or does it include C libraries? If it is pure Python then it should be easy enough to run under sl4a.

Comment: sl4a would do it as mentioned, you can just add your sympy library as part of your project and run them from sl4a. I quickly skimmed through the source I don't think there is any dependency on C libraries.

Comment: SymPy is pure Python. Thanks for the help :-). I am just unsure about the usage of sl4a- Can I use it for my application? As in, I want the interface to be Java (android) code, just the processing to be done by Python.